# MS Word shortcut key presses for inserting bookmark, sequence, and cross referencing? (Legacy menu Alt+I shortcuts)

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

It appears my MS Office had updated recently (2023, June/July), and some prior useful MS Word keyboard shortcuts no longer work.
Are there any alternative keyboard shortcuts for the following items?

- Creating a sequence (*prior:* `!ifs{down}{down}{down}{tab}{end}`)
- Creating a bookmark (*prior:* `!ik`)
- Cross referencing a bookmark (*prior:* `!inr`)

where `!` means holding down the ALT key with the next character, as per [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm) conventions.

Comment: Office 365 - still work for me.

Comment: I'm Office 365 too. I've also tried restarting MS Office; still didn't work.

Comment: Try it when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: Here is where you can go to create custom shortcuts: `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-keyboard-shortcuts-9a92343e-a781-4d5a-92f1-0f32e3ba5b4d` and here is a reference to current shortcuts: `https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2`

Comment: @Brian Creating the custom shortcut worked for a "cross reference" keyboard shortcut, thanks. I'll look into seeing how a numbered sequence gets created like that as well, specifically, it gets done by `insert -> quick parts -> Seq`

Comment: These are the Ribbon shortcuts and they still work. Word 365 version 2306. They are not ordinary shortcuts. I would write them with commas between each keystroke for clarity. Add-ins and other programs can hijack keyboard shortcuts. Here is a link to my articleson the Microsoft site about creating shortcuts. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330 https://shorturl.ac/7aqg4

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Would you be able to show how to create macros for those three functions? For instance, the insertion of a sequence can be done manually by `Insert->Quick Parts->Field->Seq` but I can't see an obvious way to make a macro within MS Word to do that. // (side-note: I thought the problem resolved itself, deleted the topic, but then found out the problem still existed, and then re-opened the topic)

Comment: The simplest way for a Seq field would be to create and save the field as an AutoText entry and use AutoComplete or attach a keyboard shortcut to it. For the bookmark or cross-reference, you could call the relevant dialogs for the selection.

Comment: See my answer, which includes a macro you could use if you want. Otherwise, learn to lift the Alt key before you press the "i" key. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The key sequence now requires a pause between the Alt key and the "i." The Alt key must be released *before* pressing the "i."

With a comma designating a pause, the old command sequence was:

```
Alt+i,f,s,{down},{down},{down},{tab},{end} - seq field
Alt+i,i,k - bookmark
Alt+i,n,r - cross-reference
```

The Alt key and the i were pressed simultaneously. Now a pause is needed with the Alt key released.

Now it is:

```
Alt,i,f,s,{down},{down},{down},{tab},{end} - seq field
Alt,i,i,k - bookmark
Alt,i,n,r - cross-reference
```

***This is not the case with the legacy Alt+E, Alt+O, and Alt+T menu shortcuts.***

Those shortcuts now work with and without releasing the Alt key.

For a [Sequence Field](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields), the simplest thing to do, though, is to create the sequence field, then save it as an [AutoText entry](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete) and either use [AutoComplete](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete) to insert it or [create a keyboard shortcut](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) associated with that entry.

[All links are to my web pages or articles.]

**The new Ribbon shortcut to insert a hyperlink is Alt,n,zl,l.**

Here is a macro to insert a bookmark around the selection.

```
Sub CreateBookmarkForSelection()
    ' Charles Kenyon 2023-08-14
    ' https://superuser.com/questions/1794055/ms-word-shortcut-key-presses-for-inserting-bookmark-sequence-and-cross-referen
    '
    Dim strBookmarkName As String
    '
    Let strBookmarkName = InputBox("What name for your bookmark?", "Bookmark Name?")
    Selection.Bookmarks.Add (strBookmarkName)
    Selection.Collapse
    MsgBox strBookmarkName & " added as a bookmark."
End Sub
```

You could add a keyboard shortcut for that if you wanted.